# Getting reference count to inspect from close calls to finalize()

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap, out-of-memory

I'm trying the last few days to solve Dalvik VM memory bug, the bug is that allocated memory for bitmap doesn't get deallocated by the GC. This is a well known open bug.

What I'm trying to do is to create object - SmartBitmap that will contain 1 bitamp and implement:

```
@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    super.finalize();
    // bitmap.finalize()
    Log.d("SmartBitmap", "inside finalize");
}

public void recycle() {
            super.recycle();
    bitmap.recycle();
            bitmap = null;
            Log.d("SmartBitmap", "inside recycle");
}
```

my aim is to observe from close that all my bitmap in the app are getting recycle() and those getting finalyze() for the GC. I cannot call finalyze() of the bitmap because it's private but I'm assumed that the finalyze() of my object will be called approxemetlly at the same time( I using bitmaps just through it).

The thing is that I except finalyze() to be called only if the reference count to the bitmap is 0, and I can't find a way to get the reference count.

Comment: If you have a look at the source for [`Bitmap`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java) you can see that it does basically that already. I've also  not heard of a known open bug with respect to that.

Comment: This is the bug I'm talking about. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8488. Thank you, I'll have a look at it

Comment: `Status: Declined` - it's not really a bug but how Java works. You can't use a finalizer to clean up faster because there is no guarantee when or if it is called. Same for setting references to `null` or calling `System.gc()`. There are simply no guarantees that the bitmap memory is ever reclaimed that way. Because of that, bitmap has `.recycle()`. Use it.

Comment: zapl, it is a bug for pre-honnycomb android version. It is well known and documented all over the web. About my solution - I know that this is not complete solution but some king of work around and probably not a good one.